# Saving ROS2 Dashing workspace to github

Tags: ros, ros2, github

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am pretty new to git and ROS2, and I want to save my ROS2 Dashing workspace as a GitHub repository. How do I do this?
Thanks in advance!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/350346/saving-ros2-dashing-workspace-to-github/) by [svintissen](https://answers.ros.org/users/53859/svintissen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 75 on 2020-04-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [christophebedard](https://answers.ros.org/users/29634/christophebedard/) on 2020-04-23**:
Seems like this is a GitHub question rather than a ROS question. By "workspace" do you mean your source code?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-04-24**:
Would #q347421 cover this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The way the instructions recommend handling this is version control for each package in your workspace, and a separate metafile that stores where each package is hosted/which branch to use

from the dashing build from source [instructions](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Installation/Dashing/Linux-Development-Setup/)

> Create a workspace and clone all
> repos:
>
> ```
> mkdir -p ~/ros2_dashing/src
> cd ~/ros2_dashing
> wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros2/ros2/dashing/ros2.repos
> vcs import src < ros2.repos
> ```

here's what the text looks like in this .repos file

```
  ros2/rclcpp:
    type: git
    url: https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp.git
    version: dashing
  ros2/rclpy:
    type: git
    url: https://github.com/ros2/rclpy.git
    version: dashing
  ros2/rcpputils:
    type: git
    url: https://github.com/ros2/rcpputils.git
    version: dashing
```

---

Originally posted by [johnconn](https://answers.ros.org/users/43713/johnconn/) with karma: 553 on 2020-04-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0